# Sed replace all characters until first space

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to replace some paths in config file. To do that I am trying to use sed.

My file looks something like that:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/tmp/tmp/tmp/config bla.bla
```

I want to replace `/tmp/tmp/tmp/config` and keep bla.bla untouched.
According to http://regexpal.com/ and http://regexr.com?362qc I should use

`sed -e 's/logging.config.file=[^\s]+/logging\.config\.file\=\/new/g' file`

But it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will replace `/tmp/tmp/...` with `aaa`:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*=\)[^ ]* \(.*\)/\1 aaa \2/g' <<< "-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/tmp/tmp/tmp/config bla.bla"
-Djava.util.logging.config.file= aaa bla.bla
```

It "saves" anything up to `=` in `\1`. Then fetches everything up to an space. Finally "saves" the rest of the string in `\2`.

The replacement is done by echoing `\1` + "new string" + `\2`.

Answer (score 1):

`\s` is not supported by `sed`. Also, the `+` must be backslashed to get its special meaning. I would also backslash the dots to prevent them from matching anything:

```
sed -e 's/logging\.config\.file=[^[:space:]]\+/logging\.config\.file\=\/new/g'
```

or, shorter

```
sed -e 's%\(logging\.config\.file=\)[^[:space:]]\+%\1/new%g'
```